# Get Vocabulary list from Tensorflow pretrained embedding

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using this https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500/2 as a pretrained embedding right now. For my application (text generation), I am interested in getting the list of tokens in the vocabulary. I know it's size 1009375. But I can't seem to get the list. I know that it has it loaded in memory but I can't seem to find it. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cache location for the `google/Wiki-words-500/2` model is `/tmp/tfhub_modules/bf115a5fe517f019bebae05b433eaeee6415f5bf` ([more on caching](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching)). You'll find the file in the `assets` directory, which contains auxiliary files:

```
wc -l /tmp/tfhub_modules/bf115a5fe517f019bebae05b433eaeee6415f5bf/assets/tokens.txt
> 1009374
```